# Box api for JS / Cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, box-api, boxapiv2

i'v spend some time investigating if i can integrate JS app (Cordova app) with Box v2 API. I would like to receive a list of file or folders. I'm not able to find a working example for JS. Is is possible at all? Are you aware of any example?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a peek at their native suggestion, https://developers.box.com/authentication-in-your-ios-app/. But if you're going to use it just inside Cordova, you will probably have to use their Oauth set-up to get credentials, https://developers.box.com/oauth/, then you can issue requests to the API for info on any part of the user's account.